# Статическое и динамическое распределение памяти

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Пишу программу на C# для обнаружения структуры с опкодами внутри процесса программы. Хочется выяснить следующее, использую дизассемблер для просмотра кода программы в дизассемблированном виде, вижу такую запись на месте адреса: iw3sp.exe + 243AF0.
Понятное дело, что это адрес опкода, который выполняет перемещение значения в регистр eax и то, что iw3sp.exe имеет адрес 00400000, к нему прибавляется смещение 243AF0, что в сумме получается адрес нашего опкода.
Меняется ли адрес опкода при статическом распределении памяти и при динамическом? Меняется ли базовый адрес iw3sp.exe и смещение к опкоду при статическом распределении памяти и при динамическом?[image: Дизассемблированный код]

Comment: Очень путано сформулировано. "программу на C# для обнаружения структуры с опкодами внутри процесса программы" - какой-такой структуры? процесса какой программы - той, что пишете или другой? "Меняется ли адрес опкода при статическом распределении памяти и при динамическом?" - в какой программе память распределяем? Ну и до кучи, что вы подразумеваете под статическим/динамическим распределением? Они ж не взаимоисключающие.. В общем, поконкретней бы.

Comment: Всё очень просто: на C# пишу программу для поиска сигнатур с опкодами, в другой программе (любой), динамическое распределение памяти имеется ввиду, что при каждом перезапуске будут новые адреса выделяться.

Comment: я глянул ваш профиль, поэтому позволю себе такой вопрос :) - вы в курсе что пользовательские процессы в Windows не могут напрямую видеть память друг друга?

Comment: Я использую отладчик

Comment: Ок. Т.е. вы анализируете не память процесса, а текстовый файл приготовленный отладчиком, я так понял. И говорим мы о Win32 на х86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На базе того, что мне удалось клещами из вас выдрать, ответ будет такой :)
"Меняется ли адрес опкода при статическом распределении памяти и при динамическом?"

Адрес опкода в памяти может меняться как угодно без всякой связи со способом выделения памяти. Потому что куда грузить код - решает ОС (но есть нюансы). Ищите по ключевым словам windows, PE format, relocation, ASLR (address space layout randomization).

"Меняется ли базовый адрес iw3sp.exe и смещение к опкоду при статическом распределении памяти и при динамическом?"

Про базовый адрес смотри выше. А вот смещение, *на мой взгляд*, меняться не может (за исключением особых случаев типа самомодифицирующегося кода и тому подобных advanced трюков, о которых сейчас не стоит). Но возможно я упускаю что-то из виду, пусть знатоки поправят. В любом случае я не вижу здесь связи с динамическим выделением памяти, так как память выделяется для данных, а не для кода и не внутри сегмента кода...

Ну и в дополнение к комментариям - адреса, показываемые отладчиком, в общем случае могут не иметь отношения к адресам в памяти. Впрочем, к вопросу это отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это значение является относительным виртуальным адресом, которое всегда будет равно этому значению на текущем патче.
RVA - это сокращение от Relative Virtual Address, т.е. относительный виртуальный адрес. "Относительно чего?" - спросите вы. "Относительно Image Base" - отвечу я. Например, если какая-либо строка хранится в памяти по адресу 450000h, и Image Base = 400000h, то RVA этой строки равен 450000h - 400000h = 50000h